# Speed of Android mobile

Tags: android

How to calculate the speed with which android mobile is moving, i.e user with mobile in his pocket/hand. Basically I would like to invoke some activity based on the user's speed, how will I calculate? based on what parameters in mobile. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [MyTracks](http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/)'s src code. They do exactly what you want.

Comment: I am not able to figure out ..where exactly is the speed calculation part of it . Can you guide me. thanks

Comment: check this: http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/stats/TripStatistics.java

Comment: @Macarse: can you send us the source code of that seems that there are some problems with the url which you have mention above.

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible by using GPS. You can take reference of two places and then find out the time required to travel from one place to another by using gps.